# How can I set specific colors in ggraph links according to a treshold value?

Tags: r, ggplot2, network-programming, ggraph

I need some help with a network I'm trying to plot with ggraph. I want that the edges color depend on the value of  the weight in my edges data frame. I've tried the code below (among others) with no result. Anyone familiar with this subject? Thank you !

```
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)

# Data frame nodes
nodes <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  label = c("Especie1", "Especie2", "Especie3", "Especie4", "Especie5")
)

# Data frame edges
edges <- data.frame(
  from = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3),
  to = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 5),
  weight = c(60, 40, 30, 70, 80, 90, 20)
)

# I create the graph
graph <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, vertices = nodes)

# Graphic with ggraph

ggraph(graph, layout = "stress") +
  geom_edge_link(aes(color = ifelse(edges$weight > 50, "Above Threshold", "Below Threshold"))) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = label)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Above Threshold" = "red", "Below Threshold" = "yellow")) +
  theme_void()
```

The code I've tried chooses two random colors for the categories created "Above Threshold" and "Below Threshold" but no the one I choose in "scale_color_manual"

Answer (score 0):

Use `scale_edge_color_manual()` instead of `scale_color_manual()`.

```r
ggraph(graph, layout = "stress") +
  geom_edge_link(aes(color = ifelse(edges$weight > 50, "Above Threshold", "Below Threshold"))) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = label)) +
  scale_edge_color_manual(values = c("Above Threshold" = "red", "Below Threshold" = "yellow")) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]